# Change the counter of subcaptionbox

Tags: subcaption

I'm using `\subcaptionbox` command provided by`subcaption` package to get subfigure.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        % \setcounter{subfloat}{10}
        \subcaptionbox{exa\label{exa}}[.4\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
        \subcaptionbox{exb\label{exb}}[.4\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
        \caption{total}\label{total}
    \end{figure}
    \ref{exa}
\end{document}
```

I got [image]

And now I want to change the counter number of subcaptionbox. For example, I'd like to make subcaptionbox's counter start with 10, not with 1. I've seen `subcaption.sty` but I didn't get information of what the counter name of `\subcaptionbox` is. How can I change it's counter?

---

Here I'll clarify my question. I'd want the subcaptions to be labelled `(k)`, `(l)`, `(m)` etc instead of `(a)`, `(b)`, `(c)` etc.

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to achieve. E.g., do you want the `figure` number to say `11` rather than `1`? Or you do you want the subcaptions to be labelled `(k)`, `(l)`, `(m)` etc instead of `(a)`, `(b)`, `(c)` etc?

Comment: @Mico In my example, I'd like to set `exa`'s counter to `(k)`, and `exb`'s counter to `(l)`.

Comment: When using the `subfigure`, `subfig`, or `subcaption` package the sub-counter for `figure` is named `subfigure`, so `\setcounter{subfigure}{...}` should do the trick.

Comment: @P.M.I've tried `\setcounter{subfigure}{10}`. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems strange for `\subcaptionbox`. Any command to operate `subfigure` counter before the first `\subcaptionbox` will have no effect. But from the second `\subcaptionbox`, it will be all right. So add a `\subcaptionnox*{}{}` before `\setcounter{subfigure}{10}`

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \subcaptionbox*{}{}
        \setcounter{subfigure}{10}
        \subcaptionbox{exa\label{exa}}[.4\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
        \subcaptionbox{exb\label{exb}}[.4\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
        \caption{total}\label{total}
    \end{figure}
    \ref{exa}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first `\subcaption` will perform `\stepcounter{figure}` which resets the subfigure counter. It firstly checks counter `caption@flags` to determine whether the step operation is performed, the code is somewhat like (in definition of `\caption@subtypehook`, exposition only in C++)

```
enum CaptionFlag {
    ContinuedFloat = 0b001;
    Caption        = 0b010;
    Subcaption     = 0b100;
};

int& flag= GetCounter("caption@flags");
if ((flag & Caption) == 0 && (flag & Subcaption) == 0)
{
    if (flag & ContinuedFloat)
        flag &= ~ContinuedFloat;
    else
        StepCounter("figure");
    flag |= Subcaption;
}
```

To avoid this, manually `\stepcounter{figure}`and set `caption@flags` to 1–7 (I've not dived in, but 4 is always safe)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \stepcounter{figure}
        \setcounter{caption@flags}{4}
        \setcounter{subfigure}{10}
        
        \subcaptionbox{exa\label{exa}}[.4\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
        \subcaptionbox{exb\label{exb}}[.4\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
        \caption{total}\label{total}
    \end{figure}
    \ref{exa}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One could use `\phantomsubcaption` to skip the sub-figures (a) to (j):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        {\phantomsubcaption}% (a)
        {\phantomsubcaption}% (b)
        {\phantomsubcaption}% (c)
        {\phantomsubcaption}% (d)
        {\phantomsubcaption}% (e)
        {\phantomsubcaption}% (f)
        {\phantomsubcaption}% (g)
        {\phantomsubcaption}% (h)
        {\phantomsubcaption}% (i)
        {\phantomsubcaption}% (j)
        \subcaptionbox{exa\label{exa}}[.4\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
        \subcaptionbox{exb\label{exb}}[.4\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
        \caption{total}\label{total}
    \end{figure}
    \ref{exa}
\end{document}
```

As alternative one could use the combination `\phantomsubcaption` plus `\setcounter{subfigure}{...}`. This is basically the same solution as the ones from @Misaya and @TuffContender but uses `\phantomsubcaption` instead of an empty `\subcaptionbox` or internal flag manipulation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        {\phantomsubcaption}% (a)
        \setcounter{subfigure}{10}
        \subcaptionbox{exa\label{exa}}[.4\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
        \subcaptionbox{exb\label{exb}}[.4\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
        \caption{total}\label{total}
    \end{figure}
    \ref{exa}
\end{document}
```

(Personally I like the 1st solution of mine more than the 2nd one since it does not rely on how the subcaption package works internally.)